# Firefox 8.0 will not automatically log into sites between sessions

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using Firefox 8.0 on Ubuntu 10.10

When I close and restart my browser I am not automatically logged into web sites where I have selected the option to do so.

Edit > Preferences > Privacy is set to accept cookies from sites, to accept 3rd part cookies and to keep cookies until they expire.

I logged in as root and went into my home directory and ran the command chmod -R 777 .mozilla on my .mozilla directory.   It didn't help.

I also noticed that firefox is not completely turning off when I close the browser.  When I close the browser, a firefox process still runs.

Anyone have any ideas what this is about or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled all of my plugins, addons, extensions etc.  This did not help.
So...

I completely uninstalled Firefox 8 and totally purged my .mozzilla directory ( after saving a copy of the bookmarks ).

I noticed that under edit, preferences the "privacy" tab has a different UI.  Maybe something didn't get updated via Ubuntu correctly and that caused my issue.

My new installation is free from both problems.